# Optimisation problem regarding petrol cost

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, relations

So here is how the question goes:

After travelling a certain distance of 20 km, a person suddenly remembers that he forgot to turn off the tap in his garden. He decides to turn around and return home to close the tap.

The cost of water, at the rate at which water is flowing out of the tap, is $1.6$ per hour.

The cost of petrol is $1.2+\frac{1}{4000}x$ per km, where $x$ is the average speed in km/h.

What is the average speed at which the person must travel home to keep his total cost a minimum?

What I know so far:

- To get an equation relating total cost and one other variable
- Take its derivative and find minimum

However, to do the first step, I want the equation in terms of one variable, not two as I get:

Let $C$ = total cost

$C$ = $1.6t + 1.2+\frac{1}{4000}x$

Need help thanks!

Comment: The average speed is distance divided by time, so it can be expressed in terms of your other variable.

Comment: As distance to travel is $20$ km, $x = \frac{20}{t}$. Then differentiate $C$ wrt. $t$ and follow standard steps to find minima.